# How to Use autocompleteComponents in PlacePicker Package Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-place-picker

I am Using the [PlacePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_place_picker) Package for Flutter , the package has a parameter called

> autocompleteComponents : A grouping of places to which you would like to restrict your results. Currently, you can use components to filter by up to 5 countries.

but I can't find anywhere how to use this parameter i can't initiate a list of components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Answer

```
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart' as google_maps_api;
...
PlacePicker(
apiKey: APIKeys.apiKey,   // Put YOUR OWN KEY here.
autocompleteComponents: [
    google_maps_api.Component("country", "fr") //restrict search results to France
],
onPlacePicked: (result) { 
    print(result.address); 
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
},
initialPosition: HomePage.kInitialPosition,
    useCurrentLocation: true,
),
```

source [an example of how to use autocompleteComponents #111](https://githubmemory.com/repo/fysoul17/google_maps_place_picker/issues/111)